# I deleted my Classes files that include my UIView Controller Classes *. and *.h files

Tags: ios, xcode, recovery

I deleted my Classes files that include my UIView Controller Classses *. and *.h files How i get back them please help because i deleted my all files

Answer (score 3):

If you have a version control system, just recover the files from its history. If you don’t have a version control system, you have just been given a perfect reason to start using one.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try a file undelete utility, if you're not using a VCS.

Comment: this is one of those things Time Machine (delivered as a standard feature of MacOS as of 10.5) is perfect for...

Comment: i didnt use a version control system and i didnt start Time Machine utility
in this case  can you help me ?

Comment: If you really need the data back and don’t have any kind of backup, immediately stop using the system. Then mount the drive to another computer and try some undeleting utility as suggested by Robert. Or, as a last resort, take it to a specialist. And above all, *start backing up*.